# Weird Codeigniter query builder bug when running Select query

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

I'm working on a query that checks if a user exists in the database. The query returns an error :

> "Table inventory_db.tbl_userss' doesn't exists".

The problem is in my code I'm cleary stating that the table name is just **tbl_users** not **tbl_userss**.

```
$query = $this->db->select('username')
    ->where('username', $username)
    ->get('tbl_users');

return $query->row();
```

Just yesterday it was working fine, didn't changed anything in my code. If it helps the database collation is `utf-8 unicode_ci`.

Comment: Can you post the error stack trace please?

Comment: RDBMS you're using?

Comment: try entering the table name qualified by the db name, `inventory_db.tbl_users`

Comment: @marvinIsSacul MySQL, tried `inventory_db.tbl_users` same error. I also tried to alter the table to `tbl_user` then in my query I used `tbl_user`, same error.

Comment: also tried `$query = $this->db->query("SELECT username FROM tbl_user WHERE username = '$username'");`, same error.

Comment: Try changing your table name to `tbl_userss` and leave your code unchanged, and see...

Comment: changed table name to `tbl_userss` throws a `Table 'inventory_db.tbl_users' doesn't exist` error. Reverted to `tbl_users` table name throws a `Table 'inventory_db.tbl_userss' doesn't exist` error. No changes made on the query.